# Upload uiimage base64 encoded

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, swift3

I am trying to upload an uiview (chart) but I receiving null picture at email (from webservice)... Android is working

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    self.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    let jpegCompressionQuality: CGFloat = 1
    let imgData:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenShot!,jpegCompressionQuality)!
    let lengthOfData = imgData.count
    let strBase64 = imgData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myws.com/Chart.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "data=\(strBase64)&email=admin@myws.com"
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("\(lengthOfData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: I think you are missing a few things here like setting value for httpheaderfield etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for taking a screen shot of iOS device is fine. I think your post request for uploading UIImage to server lacked the following things:

```
let imgData:NSData = data        
let lengthOfData = imgData.length
// ENCODINGDATA - whatever encoding your server wants here
request.addValue(ENCODINGDATA, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("\(lengthOfData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
```

Apart from this, it's better to use `AlamoFire` to handle complex server tasks like this. It makes it easier. It can be done like this

```
let imageData = UIPNGRepresentation(image)!

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in

   debugPrint(response)
}
```

Feel free to suggest edits to make this better. Please let me know if there are any mistakes or drawbacks in my answer

Comment: is the image you are receiving at server still empty?

Comment: yes, using  `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenShot!, nil, nil, nil)` the image goes correctly to phone storage

Comment: Try uploading image using `Alamofire` library and check if it is uploading https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: I used [multipart](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/) and works. Thanks!